# PHPCS different ruleset for different directories

Tags: php, phpcs

I am currently working on cleaning up an existing codebase and one of the aspects involve using PHPCS. This is my `phpcs.xml` file at the moment:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<ruleset name='MyApplication'>
    <arg name='encoding' value='utf-8'/>
    <arg name='extensions' value='php'/>
    <arg name='warning-severity' value='0'/>
    <arg name='colors'/>
    <arg value='p'/>

    <exclude-pattern>vendor/*</exclude-pattern>
    <exclude-pattern>node_modules/*</exclude-pattern>

    <rule ref='PSR1'></rule>
</ruleset>
```

I'd like to modify it so that PSR-2 is applied to certain directories (e.g. `foo/` and `bar/`) while the remaining directories are checked against PSR-1.

I found the `<exclude-pattern>` option in the manual that can be placed as child elements of the `<rule>` element but I need the opposite of that.

Comment: I think you should ask for a [feature request in issues of PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/issues). 

It will increase a chance to add it. Or you'll get a useful feedback there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create multiple configs and use `--standard` option to load them:

```
vendor/bin/phpcs source-to-check --standard first-settings.xml 
vendor/bin/phpcs another-to-check --standard second-settings.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

```
./vendor/bin/phpcs /project/path --standard=/other/path/phpcs.xml
```